# In fish shell, how to iterate over files using wildcard and variable?

Tags: fish

If I run:

```
for f in *1000.png
   echo $f
end
```

I get

```
1000.png
11000.png
21000.png
```

I would like to do something like:

```
for i in 1 2 3
    for f in *$i000.png
         echo $f
    end
end
```

To get

```
1000.png
11000.png
21000.png
2000.png
12000.png
22000.png
3000.png
13000.png
23000.png
```

Instead, it outputs nothing.

I also tried:

```
for i in 1 2
    set name "*"$i"000.png"
    for f in (ls $name)
        echo $f
    end
end
```

Outputting:

```
ls: *1000.png: No such file or directory
ls: *2000.png: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are attempting to referencing the `i` variable in `*$i000.png`, your shell thinks that `$i000` means you are trying to reference the `i000` variable, not `i` followed by three zeroes like you want.

Use `{$var_name}` to access variables in fish, generally its a good idea to *always* reference shell variables this way.

So your your case, in the second line use:

```
    for f in *{$i}000.png
```

Answer (score 15):

To avoid trying to expand the variable `$i000`, you would do

```
for i in 1 2 3
    for f in *{$i}000.png
         echo $f
    end
end
```

Or, avoid the outer loop altogether:

```
for f in *{1,2,3}000.png
```